# How to feed a value from an output object as an input into another output object?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a simulation-based app.  I have 2 initial numeric input objects, "max imp count" and "population size". Based on what is fed into these numeric input objects, the app generates 2 more input objects (really as output objects)- "select_proportion" and "select_probability". If the "max imp count" is 3, the app should generate 8 new input objects- 4 which ask for proportion (proportion0, proportion1, proportion2, proportion3), and 4 of which ask for probability0, probability1, probability2 and probability3. I want to feed these proportion and probability values into sample functions that work in the following manner:

1) sample(c(0,input$max_imp, 1), size=input$population, replace=TRUE, prob= *these take the proportion values*

sample for binary values for all proportion brackets:
2) sample(c(0,1), length(proportion_i), replace=TRUE, prob=*these take the probability values*)

Ideally, I would like to have this all in a dataframe where I have columns for which proportion bracket a record belongs to and whether they have 0 or 1.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simulation"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      numericInput("max_imp", "max imp count", 0, min = 0, max = 15, step = 1),
      numericInput("population", "population size", 1, min = 0, max = 100000, step = 1),
      menuItemOutput("menuitem")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("select_proportion"),
    uiOutput("select_probability")
  ))


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$select_proportion = renderUI(
      lapply(0:(input$max_imp), function(i){
      numericInput(inputId = "i1", label = paste0("proportion",i), 0, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.05)}))

    output$select_probability = renderUI(
    lapply(0:(input$max_imp), function(i){
      numericInput(inputId = "i2", label = paste0("probability",i), 0, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.05)}))

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I want to pass the values in output$select_proportion as a vector into the prob argument in the sample function.  How would this be implemented?

Comment: store the values in ```reactive``` expressions, so that you can then use them in as many outputs you want

Answer (score 0):

Your output elements are only UI container which are then filled with the input elements defined in the renderUI functions. You can easily access the values of these input elements as you do it with your other inputs.

The only thing here is that you have to set the IDs of the inputs in a dynamic way e.g. instead of `id = "i2"` for the second input use `id = paste("input", i, "2", sep = "-")`. This will create you `input$max_imp + 1` different inputs. The values can then be accessed via `input$input_1_2`.

BR
Sebastian

Comment: Thank you! I added in the IDs of the second input as ```id=paste("input, i, "prop", sep="-")```. I now want to select all columns in the input object which have "prop" in their names. I tried ```input[, grepl("prop", names(input)]```. This doesn't seem to work. Would you know why?

Comment: The variable `input` is a reactive variable. You have to reformat it first to a list: `input_list <- reactiveValuesToList(input)` and then you can select the desired elements with your `grepl` command.